# how to count for a range of integers in a list

Tags: python, list, count, range, probability

I am trying to find the probability of the numbers in a list.I have a list say:

```
a =[62.0, 0.0, 67.0, 69.0, 0.0, 76.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 70.0, 73.0, 0.0, 0.0, 56.0, 80.0, 0.0, 59.0, 65.0, 78.0, 0.0, 43.0, 0.0, 87.0]
```

i want to find out the probability of number from 0-25,25-50,50-100 and more than 100.
i tried using this:

```
a.count(range(25))/len(a)
a.count(range(25,50))/len(a)
```

But am not getting the required results.
Can someone help with whats wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a.count(range(25))` gives 0 because `range(25)` isn't an element of `a`.  What you want to count is the occurrences of each individual element of `range(25)` within `a`, e.g.:

```
>>> sum(a.count(i) for i in range(25))
9
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over each element of `a` and check it for inclusion in the range (I think this'll be a bit faster since in theory you don't need to iterate over a range to test whether something is in it):

```
>>> sum(i in range(25) for i in a)
9
```

Comment: yeah, they both work as intended, however, as the grouping increases like 100-150, 150-200 and so on it will be too many lines of code. But for now, in my case this works perfectly, thank you, sir.

Comment: Testing the time with the `timeit` module (for number=100,000), they both take around 3 seconds. First method takes around 3.3 seconds and the second method takes around 3 seeconds. So yes, the second method is faster but only slightly (0.3 sec difference for 100000 runs is pretty small id say)

Comment: @Kshtj If the answer is what you needed, please consider accepting it so that the question isnt left unanswered

Comment: It'd be very easy to increase the range in a loop.  `[sum(a.count(i) for i in range(25 * r, 25 * (r + 1))) for r in range(10)]` or whatever.

Comment: The use of `sum` and `range` is unnecessarily inefficient. A much more efficient solution is simply: `len([i for i in a if 0 <= i <= 25])`. This has the added benefit of handling fractional values as well.

Comment: allocating a whole extra list?  yikes

Comment: @Samwise If you're worried about that, `sum(0 <= i <= 25 for i in a)` will still be much more efficient. But the input list would have to be huge to be worth bothering with it.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Samwise's answer, since OP @Kshtj said in a comment they don't want too many lines of code... You can simply write a `function` or `lambda` to get the frequency as such, which will be more easily scalable:

```
get_freq = lambda a, low, high: sum(low <= i < high for i in a) / len(a)

>>>get_freq(a, 0, 25)
0.391304347826087
>>>get_freq(a, 50, 100)
0.5652173913043478
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> len(list(filter(lambda x: x<=25, a)))/len(a)
0.391304347826087
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [62.0, 0.0, 67.0, 69.0, 0.0, 76.0, 0.0, 0.0, 69.0, 70.0, 73.0, 0.0, 0.0, 56.0, 80.0, 0.0, 59.0, 65.0, 78.0, 0.0, 43.0, 0.0, 87.0]

print("0-25:", len(list(filter(lambda x: 0 <= x <= 25, a))) / len(a))
print("25-50:", len(list(filter(lambda x: 25 < x <= 50, a))) / len(a))
print("50-100:", len(list(filter(lambda x: 50 < x <= 100, a))) / len(a))
print(">100:", len(list(filter(lambda x: x > 100, a))) / len(a))
```

Output

```
0-25: 0.391304347826087
25-50: 0.043478260869565216
50-100: 0.5652173913043478
>100: 0.0
```